# Can I hide a charge behind a black hole?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes

Suppose that you are standing on one side of a black hole.  I'm standing directly opposite you, on the other side of the BH, and I'm holding a charged particle.  Is it possible for us to be positioned such that you cannot detect the particle's electric field?

My thought process is this: There seems to be some sense in which we can think of the electric field lines as having to "wrap around" the BH.  But if this is so, then perhaps there's no guarantee that the field lines can wrap tightly enough around the BH to reach you if you're standing on the opposite side.

Comment: You might be interested in this paper by Leonhardt and Philbin (http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0607418). In particular they show its possible (in theory, of course) to design material that has a negative refractive index. This is similar to the cloaking device you describe (p.6 ,section 3.1). So, yes! It is certainly possible =)

Comment: I disagree, cloaking by light refraction is different to space-time geometry distorting electric fields. To my knowledge, if the charged particle existed at a time before the BH, then the field lines will exist even if it falls into the BH - it's reasonable to think that unless you spontaneously created a charged particle within the horizon, it would be "detectable" (but perhaps not in practice due to the small size of the charge).